# System getting shutdown automotacally

Tags: shutdown, system

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS gets shutdown automatically by 11 AM. I've cleared all my scheduled tasks but then getting shutdown. Help me sort out this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jan  7 11:00:01 hemnath-System-Product-Name kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jan  7 11:00:01 hemnath-System-Product-Name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="593" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan  7 11:00:47 hemnath-System-Product-Name kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jan  7 11:00:47 hemnath-System-Product-Name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="611" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

Comment: System logs attached above

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files in /var/log directory.

I would start there with system log:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Please find the logs captured today during the time of auto shutdown,                                                        Jan  2 08:35:03 hemnath-System-Product-Name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="706" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan  2 11:28:54 hemnath-System-Product-Name kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jan  2 11:28:54 hemnath-System-Product-Name rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="626" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start